# Big Data approach for large SQL datasets

Tags: performance, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a table with user's activities from a SaaS product(the company which I work for), this table is a `relational SQL` and does have about ~47M rows.
Every report I make takes about 2h to run, is there any approach of `Big Data` that can help me improve it's time execution? Currently we're working on a `PostgreSQL 9.5` hosted at `AWS`. I was considering something about `Amazon Redshift` but no clue if it is the best or better way to do this.

The table structure is like below:

```
id integer ,
happened_at timestamp without time zone ,
enterprise_id integer ,
trackable_id integer ,
trackable_type character varying ,
actor_id integer ,
actor_type character varying ,
key character varying ,
parameters text ,
target_id integer ,
target_type character varying ,
```

Comment: There is only one table? BTW actor_type looks functionally dependent on actor_id. Same for target_type, trackable_type, ...

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure, but you would probably get a big performance boost from moving or copying your data to Redshift and running your report queries against that. Since you are using PostgreSQL already migrating to Redshift should be fairly simple. I would recommend using the AWS Data Migration Service to copy your data to Redshift and then test running your report against that.

Comment: Are you saying you have 47 millions of millions of rows? That doesn't seem to be true given the fact that your id is only int4. Also its hard to give any advice without the actual report query and the result you want to achieve.

Comment: @Nick Biggest integer is 2,147,483,647

Comment: @Nick It's 47M actually, sorry.

Comment: @joop The schema contains 102 tables.

Comment: How do you make report? Is it single sql query? Tell us more, right now it's not enough info.

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz It's a single query with some CTE's and aggregate functions... I was wondering with it does exist an alternative to improve the speed...

Comment: You could post your query itself (with execution plan). Maybe there is room for improvement?